# for of loop that stops at last object of array

Tags: typescript

I have a for of loop, for each item in the `childElements` HTMLCollection I want to subtract the height of the elements from the parent height.

```
let height = element[0].clientHeight;
const childElements = <[HTMLElement]>element[0].children;
let i = 0;
for (const childElement of childElements) {
    if (i !== childElements.length - 1) {
        height -= Math.ceil(childElement.clientHeight);
    }
    i++;
}
return height;
```

But I want to exclude the last HTMLElement in the collection from the for loop. I've now created a i variable that is checked against the length of the collection minus 1. If that's not the case the height of the element is subtracted and i is increased.

This works fine, but it feels like I'm doing two things (for of loop and while loop). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It hit me,

```
function returnSuggestedColleaguesWithExpertiseHeight(): number {
    let height = element[0].clientHeight;
    const childElements = <[HTMLElement]>element[0].children;
    for (let i = 0; i < childElements.length - 1; i++) {
        height -= Math.ceil(childElements[i].clientHeight);
    }
    return height;
}
```